# Broken Syntax Color Coding for Python in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm trying to edit a Python file in Visual Studio Community 2017 but the syntax color coding isn't responding correctly to the code I'm writing.

The only module I'm importing from is gimpfu. Intellisense is not compatible with this module. I say this in case color coding breaks when the imports are not compatible with Intellisense.

As I try to multi-line comment the color coding does not reflect what I've commented. The Python program still runs as expected, but the color coding doesn't reflect changes properly.

I'm looking for a way to either fix the color coding or remove it completely. I have tried unchecking Text Editor > Python > Advanced > Miscellaneous Options > "Color names based on types", but this does nothing and VS still tries to color the code.